# How to force subquery in Django-ORM?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-orm

I have the following table:

```
> select * from request_tripinterval order by id


+-----+----------------------------+-------+------+-----------+---------+
| id  |         timestamp          | path  | time | params_id | trip_id |
+-----+----------------------------+-------+------+-----------+---------+
| 411 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.193870 | 47.0  | 67.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 412 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.311034 | 99.0  | 67.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 413 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.436022 | 66.0  | 67.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 414 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.544529 | 44.0  | 67.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 415 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.636328 | 16.0  | 67.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 416 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.728114 | 18.0  | 67.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 417 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.802324 | 52.0  | 67.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 418 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.886299 | 92.0  | 52.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 419 | 2019-08-25 21:09:18.977108 | 13.0  | 52.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 420 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.059118 | 5.0   | 26.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 421 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.134312 | 91.0  | 26.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 422 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.209511 | 75.0  | 87.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 423 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.275903 | 89.0  | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 424 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.358898 | 59.0  | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 425 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.427366 | 100.0 | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 426 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.543564 | 95.0  | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 427 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.654867 | 91.0  | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 428 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.742747 | 78.0  | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 429 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.826721 | 86.0  | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 430 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.901921 | 5.0   | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 431 | 2019-08-25 21:09:19.976131 | 14.0  | 80.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 432 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.051317 | 98.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 433 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.126492 | 15.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 434 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.216339 | 80.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 435 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.301297 | 94.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 436 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.399910 | 99.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 437 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.466298 | 91.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 438 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.541497 | 38.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 439 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.616683 | 36.0  | 42.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 440 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.701623 | 37.0  | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 441 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.782666 | 97.0  | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 442 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.908651 | 36.0  | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 443 | 2019-08-25 21:09:20.991640 | 40.0  | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 444 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.059015 | 3.0   | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 445 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.141037 | 35.0  | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 446 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.240623 | 7.0   | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 447 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.323633 | 56.0  | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 448 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.400760 | 4.0   | 11.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 449 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.491573 | 87.0  | 51.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 450 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.574581 | 90.0  | 51.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 451 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.664402 | 34.0  | 33.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 452 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.748376 | 9.0   | 33.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 453 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.831374 | 98.0  | 33.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 454 | 2019-08-25 21:09:21.916329 | 67.0  | 33.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 455 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.007345 | 43.0  | 33.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 456 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.082520 | 35.0  | 33.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 457 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.190918 | 69.0  | 33.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 458 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.273957 | 79.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 459 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.389165 | 59.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 460 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.464353 | 27.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 461 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.563965 | 98.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 462 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.640127 | 100.0 | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 463 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.747525 | 4.0   | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 464 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.822713 | 98.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 465 | 2019-08-25 21:09:22.922326 | 22.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 466 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.005306 | 47.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 467 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.088333 | 46.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 468 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.155681 | 13.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 469 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.231856 | 75.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 470 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.298255 | 87.0  | 6.0  |         1 |       1 |
| 471 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.372465 | 4.0   | 16.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 472 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.448619 | 67.0  | 16.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 473 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.521861 | 22.0  | 16.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 474 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.631304 | 51.0  | 19.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 475 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.706488 | 16.0  | 19.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 476 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.798287 | 87.0  | 32.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 477 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.890063 | 13.0  | 32.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 478 | 2019-08-25 21:09:23.980984 | 78.0  | 32.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 479 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.063983 | 84.0  | 32.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 480 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.138198 | 12.0  | 32.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 481 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.221197 | 27.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 482 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.296366 | 26.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 483 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.388154 | 5.0   | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 484 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.463434 | 45.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 485 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.554256 | 31.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 486 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.638232 | 40.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 487 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.746605 | 63.0  | 79.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 488 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.829607 | 80.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 489 | 2019-08-25 21:09:24.937993 | 69.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 490 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.021977 | 67.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 491 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.129387 | 82.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 492 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.245572 | 74.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 493 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.379345 | 25.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 494 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.544364 | 23.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 495 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.628341 | 24.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 496 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.702550 | 68.0  | 81.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 497 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.777737 | 68.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 498 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.862701 | 41.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 499 | 2019-08-25 21:09:25.945713 | 73.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 500 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.035520 | 44.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 501 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.110712 | 75.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 502 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.185917 | 73.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 503 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.270858 | 5.0   | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 504 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.353856 | 77.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 505 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.443675 | 47.0  | 95.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 506 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.526674 | 75.0  | 29.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 507 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.618461 | 66.0  | 29.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 508 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.693664 | 60.0  | 44.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 509 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.785455 | 48.0  | 44.0 |         1 |       1 |
| 510 | 2019-08-25 21:09:26.852823 | 51.0  | 44.0 |         1 |       1 |
+-----+----------------------------+-------+------+-----------+---------+
```

When I query it from Django-project like this:

```
id_row = Window(RowNumber(), order_by=F('id').asc())
time_row = Window(RowNumber(), partition_by=F('time'), order_by=F('id').asc())

queryset = TripInterval.objects.annotate(
  time_grp=id_row - time_row
).values(
  'time', 'time_grp'
).annotate(
  start_id=Min('id'), end_id=Max('id')
).order_by(
 'start_id'
)
```

it results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  "request_tripinterval"."time",
  (
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "request_tripinterval"."id" ASC)
    -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "request_tripinterval"."time" ORDER BY "request_tripinterval"."id" ASC)
  ) AS "time_grp",
  MIN("request_tripinterval"."id") AS "start_id",
  MAX("request_tripinterval"."id") AS "end_id" 
FROM
  "request_tripinterval"
GROUP BY
  "request_tripinterval"."time",
  (
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "request_tripinterval"."id" ASC)
    -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "request_tripinterval"."time" ORDER BY "request_tripinterval"."id" ASC)
  )
ORDER BY "start_id" ASC
```

which gives an error:

> misuse of window function ROW_NUMBER()

but what I really need is:

```
SELECT "subquery"."time" AS "time",
    MIN("subquery"."id") AS "start_id",
    MAX("subquery"."id") AS "end_id" 
FROM (
  SELECT
    "request_tripinterval"."id",
    "request_tripinterval"."time",
    (
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "request_tripinterval"."id" ASC)
      -
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "request_tripinterval"."time" ORDER BY "request_tripinterval"."id" ASC)
    ) AS "time_grp"
  FROM
    "request_tripinterval"
) as subquery
GROUP BY "time", "time_grp"
ORDER BY "start_id" ASC
```

which works fine and gives required result:

```
+------+----------+--------+
| time | start_id | end_id |
+------+----------+--------+
| 67.0 |      411 |    417 |
| 52.0 |      418 |    419 |
| 26.0 |      420 |    421 |
| 87.0 |      422 |    422 |
| 80.0 |      423 |    431 |
| 42.0 |      432 |    439 |
| 11.0 |      440 |    448 |
| 51.0 |      449 |    450 |
| 33.0 |      451 |    457 |
| 79.0 |      458 |    460 |
| 6.0  |      461 |    470 |
| 16.0 |      471 |    473 |
| 19.0 |      474 |    475 |
| 32.0 |      476 |    480 |
| 79.0 |      481 |    487 |
| 81.0 |      488 |    496 |
| 95.0 |      497 |    505 |
| 29.0 |      506 |    507 |
| 44.0 |      508 |    510 |
+------+----------+--------+
```

How can I build query with Django-ORM without RawSQL to get desired results? And how in general I can specify subquery to 'FROM' SQL-clause in Django-ORM?

Comment: Can you share your `TripInterval` model code?

Comment: first code snippet is `select * from ...` which gives all rows and column names existing in table